# Why is C# BigInteger not always the same bit length?

Tags: c#, random, biginteger

I am trying to generate 1024bits random numbers with this code:

```
var bytes = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(128);
var number = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

But when I inspect my `number` using BigInteger methods, its BitLength is always different.

For example, when running this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var bi = new BigInteger(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(128));
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {bi.GetBitLength()} bits | {bi.GetByteCount()} bytes");
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
0: 1021 bits | 128 bytes
1: 1023 bits | 128 bytes
2: 1022 bits | 128 bytes
3: 1021 bits | 128 bytes
4: 1022 bits | 128 bytes
```

What am I doing wrong / not understanding here ?

Comment: If you must have the high-order bit be a '1' then set it to a '1' and let the remaining 1023 be random.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetBitLength` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.getbitlength?view=net-8.0) as:

> Gets the number of bits required for shortest two's complement representation of the current instance without the sign bit.

And also, helpfully:

> For positive integers the return value is equal to the ordinary binary representation string length.

Now, consider two (very small) `BigInteger` values - 1 and 3. It only takes 1 bit to represent the integer value 1, whereas it takes 2 bits to represent the integer 3.

Effectively, any leading 0 bits which might have been passed in the original byte array aren't included in `GetBitLength()`.

I suspect that's absolutely fine for you, but it will definitely depend on what you're planning to do with the result. To put it another way: if you only wanted 4 bit numbers, would you want values between 0 and 15 inclusive, or between 8 and 15 inclusive? Because requiring `GetBitLength()` to return 4 would make you generate the latter... (That's effectively "3 random bits and a leading bit that's always 1".)

Comment: For e.g. RSA key pair generation you want to have a random value between 2^(l/2-1) and 2^(l/2) as a starting point to find a prime, otherwise the modulus / key size won't be of size l. So I suspect that this is **not** "absolutely fine".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Where did the OP say they were trying to do that? All we know is they're trying to create 1024 bit random number. If they're *actually* trying to create 1023 bits of randomness and *always* a leading 1 bit, that's somewhat different, right? Anyway, I've explained why it's behaving this way - it's up to the OP to determine how to use the information for their specific (but not specified here) use case.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I've clarified the last paragraph a bit to make it clear that it really does depend on the use case.